# Using the Console to Debug JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, console.log

I am trying to get better at using the Console debug my JS code, but I'm not quite sure if I am logging to the console properly.

Here is a little code example to illustrate. In this example, if you click on the black square the width changes.  Now the code works so nothing should appear in the console, but when it comes time to test new code, have I logged it appropriately?

HTML:

```
<div id="square1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#square1
{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

JS:

```
var square1 = document.getElementById("square1");

square1.onclick = function grow()
{
 if(square1.style.width=="10px")
 {
    square1.style.width="20px";
 }
 else
    {
        square1.style.width = "10px";
    }
 };

 console.log(grow());
```

Comment: `console.log(grow());` executes `grow()` and logs its return value to the console. Since the function doesn't return anything, that's `undefined`. So that's not helpful at all.

Comment: `console.log` literally only writes to the console what you give it. Nothing more, nothing less. It doesn't magically trace a function execution, or anything like that. Make it write useful statements to the console which help you follow the state of your program. There's not much more to it than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to log the final width after pressing click, you should use:

```
square1.onclick = function grow()
{
 if(square1.style.width=="10px")
 {
    square1.style.width="20px";
 }
 else
 {
    square1.style.width = "10px";
 }

 console.log(square1.style.width);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what you mean to log here is `square1.style.width`. `console.log(grow())` will always return undefined since your function returns nothing.